# Financial and real-time market-data software for the command line

Tags: command-line, terminal, ncurses

I can easily build HUDs at command prompts for stuff like the weather, my to-dos, Twitter, IRC, etcetera; but the one thing I’m always stuck going to my iPhone or browser for, constantly, is real-time (or slightly delayed) market data.

Does anybody know of an Ncurses HUD or something of that nature for financial information, market status, things like that?